# R import csv data with function

Tags: r, function

I want to create my owm function to read `.csv` data. The code is:

```
my_read_data <- function(x){
data <- data.table::fread(x, header = T, strip.white = T)
data <- data[data[5] != 0,]
data <- as.Date(data[9])
data <- as.Date(data[16])
}
```

However, when I read my data, I get this `Error`:

```
Data <- my_read_data("mydata.csv")
Error in `[.data.table`(data, data[5] != 0, ) : 
i is invalid type (matrix). Perhaps in future a 2 column matrix could return a list of elements of DT (in the spirit of A[B] in FAQ 2.14). Please let datatable-help know if you'd like this, or add your comments to FR #657.
```

What I want is if `column 5` appear `0`, delete that row. Set `Column 9 & 10` formats.
Any suggestion?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @thelatemail's comment. Now, I edit my code in th following:

```
my_read_data <- function(x){
data <- data.table::fread(x, header = T, strip.white = T)
data <- data[data[[5]] != 0,]
data <- as.Date(data[9])
data <- as.Date(data[16])
}
```

However, `as.Date` not work. After running my function, it doesn't create data.

Comment: `data[data[[5]] != 0,]` I think you want. Though it would probably be preferable to refer to columns by name

Comment: @thelatemail thanks. It works. However, `as.Date` not work. I edit my question.

Comment: It's the same problem still - `data[9]` selects a row, you want `data[[9]]`. Some simple debugging would have identified your issue. You are also overwriting the whole `data` object instead of a single column - I gather this is not what you want to do.

Comment: @thelatemail With a vanilla data.frame, `data[9]` will return a data.frame of the ninth column (unlike data.table). The variants (data.table, tibble) are consistent with base in that `data[[9]]` always extracts the ninth column as a vector.

Comment: @alistaire - I'm aware of that - but `fread` always returns a `data.table` I believe.

Comment: @thelatemail Oops! I totally overlooked that. Not sure if it should get tagged...it's quasi-relevant.

Comment: it doesn't show datatable.

Comment: `?fread` - `data.table=` argument - '*TRUE returns a data.table. FALSE returns a data.frame.*', with `TRUE` being the default as per `getOption("datatable.fread.datatable")`

Answer (score 0):

`as.date()` works in the following manner and you can change the forma to the format you want

```
x<- as.Date(dates,format = "%m/%d/%y")
```